# Keeping track of how many instantiation of a Form is opened or closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application with three forms. `MainForm`, `QuestionForm`, and `ViewItemsForm`. The `MainForm` is always displayed. The `MainForm` contains two `buttons` and two read-only `textboxes`. One of the `buttons` allows the user to open up multiple instance of the `QuestionForm` which should then display the count of how many are open in one of the textboxes in the `MainForm`. If one of the `QuestionForms` is closed, the count inside the `textbox` should go down to.

I've tried to implement the trigger inside the button that opens the `QuestionFrom`, and another when the form is closed, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private void questionFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      QuestionForm questionFormOpen = new QuestionForm();
      questionFormOpen.Show();
   }

  private void countOfQuestionForm_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     countOfQuestionForm.Text = //Assign the count here
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx) *Property* like the following code:

```
private void questionFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QuestionForm questionFormOpen = new QuestionForm();
    questionFormOpen.Show();
    questionFormOpen.Shown += Fr_Closed;
    questionFormOpen.Disposed += Fr_Closed;
}
private void Fr_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  countOfQuestionForm.Text = Application.OpenForms.OfType<QuestionForm>().Count().ToString();
}
```